# Initialization for logger is unsuccessful

Tags: log4j

I am using the below mentioned log4j.properties file in tomcat 6.0.35

```
log4j.appender.request=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.request.Append=true
log4j.fileName=logs/test
log4j.appender.request.File=${log4j.fileName}.log
log4j.appender.request.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.request.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${log4j.fileName}.%i.log.zip
log4j.appender.request.RollingPolicy.MinIndex=1
log4j.appender.request.RollingPolicy.MaxIndex=10

log4j.appender.request.TriggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.request.TriggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=10485760

log4j.appender.request.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.request.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=info, request
```

But I get the following messages returned

```
log4j:WARN Failed to set property [rollingPolicy] to value "org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy".
log4j:WARN Failed to set property [triggeringPolicy] to value "org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy".
log4j:WARN Please set a rolling policy for the RollingFileAppender named 'request'
log4j:WARN Failed to set property [rollingPolicy] to value "org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy".
log4j:WARN Failed to set property [triggeringPolicy] to value "org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy".
log4j:WARN Please set a rolling policy for the RollingFileAppender named 'request'
log4j:ERROR No output stream or file set for the appender named [request].
```

There is some problem with setting the properties in log4j configuration. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried setting log4j.jar in your classpath

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today using apache-log4j-extras1.1.jar.  After a while of wrestling I found that my log4j.jar being version 1.2.14 was the problem.  I updated to 1.2.17 and it fixed my issue.  Make sure it sits before any other log4j in your tomcat (or in your app).